# How to change browser URL dynamically in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My app works perfectly for below code. ie open google.com once button is clicked.

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import webbrowser

Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5
        cols: 1
        padding: root.width*0.1
        Button:
            background_normal: ''
            background_color:(0.862, 0.078, 0.235, 0.9)
            text: 'PLAY'
            font_size: '20sp'
            on_press: root.val1()
''')

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val1(self):
        print "i am executed"
        webbrowser.open("http://google.com/")

sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Now, suppose someone is using my app and after few days i want to change url from google.com to yahoo.com, what approach should i follow. I am completely clueless about it. Should i get a domain name and change it redirection like abc.com/test.html to redirect to google.com and then change the redirection to yahoo.com later or some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two idea for this:

1. keep a array of urls in your code and choose one randomly to use.
2. If you maintain a server, then you can use an static url from where your program will receive data which are nothing but url or url list and use it.

Comment: no, i mean, suppose i am showing an advertisement of company A on button click. Later, i want to show advertisement of company B. How to take such control with me once my app is released with advertisement of company A.

Comment: Oh, you should add this to your question then.